# react lifecycle componentWillReceiveProps how to change getDerivedStateFromProps then send redux action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

componentWillReceiveProps as the warning lifecycle after react version 16.3, I am updating the old version to 16.4.2

The following are the common practices I used in the old version.

Receive actions in the componentWillReceiveProps cycle and call the function of this.props.xxxxActionsCreator dispatch redux action to drive itself and other component updates but after 16.3, getDerivedStateFromProps is static and cannot call this.

I would like to ask how to update the practice is the most appropriate?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Modal from 'antd/lib/modal';
import * as DeleteDialogActions from '../Actions/DeleteDialogActions';

export default class DeleteDialogView extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showDialog: false
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        switch (nextProps.actionType) {
            case DeleteDialogActions.SHOW_DELETE_DIALOG:
            case DeleteDialogActions.HIDE_DELETE_DIALOG:
                this.showDialog();
                break;
            case DeleteDialogActions.DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS:
                this.props.DeleteDialogActionsCreator.updateDialog();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    showDialog = () => {
        this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog});
        this.props.DeleteDialogActionsCreator.updateDialog();
    };

    handleOk = () => {
        this.props.DeleteDialogActionsCreator.doDeleteItem(this.props.deleteItemId);
        this.setState({showDialog: false});
    };

    handleCancel = () => {
        this.setState({showDialog: false});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal
                    title="Delete"
                    visible={this.state.showDialog}
                    onOk={this.handleOk}
                    onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                    className="delete-dialog"
                >
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the item with device ID {this.props.deleteItemId} ?</p>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DeleteDialogView.defaultProps = {
    deleteItemId: 0
};

DeleteDialogView.propTypes = {
    actionType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    deleteItemId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    DeleteDialogActionsCreator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot access `this` inside the **static** `getDerivedStateFromProps`  method  you’ll have to store or return a state by doing something like `return { showDialog: true };` which is equivalent to `this.setState({showDialog: true})`. So you can check the state in `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method which will be only triggered if `getDerivedStateFromProps` returns a value which is not null.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if(this.state.showDialog){
           this.showDialog();
      }
     if(this.state.updateDialog){
      this.props.DeleteDialogActionsCreator.updateDialog();
     }
  }




   getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
          switch (nextProps.actionType) {
            case DeleteDialogActions.SHOW_DELETE_DIALOG:
            case DeleteDialogActions.HIDE_DELETE_DIALOG:
                 return { showDialog: true };
                break;
            case DeleteDialogActions.DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS:
                 return { updateDialog: true };
                break;
            default:
                 return null;
                break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but every time you want to add a dispatch action, you have to add code in state and componentDidUpdate. It feels very complicated.